# MongoDB count number of non-missing fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using the following code to calculate average and standard deviation of a field named "b" in my collection.

```
db.ctg.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "b",           
           avg: { $avg: "$b" },
           stdev: { $stdDevPop: "$b" }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

The result is:

```
{ "_id" : "b", "avg" : 878.4397930385701, "stdev" : 893.8744489449962 }
```

I need to add number of non missing elements of "b" to my result so it looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : "b", "avg" : 878.4397930385701, "stdev" : 893.8744489449962, "nonmissing": 2126 }
```

How can I do this in the query above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result of [$avg](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/index.html) & [$stdDevPop](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/stdDevPop/index.html) doesn't change even after removal of documents where `b` doesn't exists (`$avg` ignores all docs where field is non-numeric/missing), So you can try below query.

**Query :**

```
db.ctg.aggregate([
        { $match: { b: { $exists: true } } },
        {
            $group:
            {
                _id: "b",
                avg: { $avg: "$b" },
                stdev: { $stdDevPop: "$b" },
                nonMissing: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        }
    ])
```